# Transform label into input text

Tags: javascript, dom, contenteditable, inplace-editing

There's some big companies that allow you to click on a label and trigger a event that transform that tag into a editable tag. So you can make whatever changes you want and then press enter(or something else) to edit(mostly using ajax).

Is there such a way of doing that using javascript or whatever?

Already tried change the tagName attribute, but I think this obviously wouldn't work.

Does someone got a approach?

p.s.: Haven't find this in SO. I'm sorry if I didn't use the right keywords to search for it.

Comment: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Comment: That's so what I want. Is that cross-browser? Why not an answer, by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need edit just a plain text, then use solution mentioned by *BotskoNet*.

If you need more editing options (a WYSIWYG editor), then you should try e.g. http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline. CKEditor is based on `contenteditable` mentioned by *elclanrs*, but it fixes huge amount of browsers' bugs and unifies their behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple in-line editing scripts/plugins out there. One I've used recently with success was:

http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/

For full cross-browser support they usually grab the text, replace the element with an `input type="text"` and then grab the value and restore the original element with the new text when you're done.

Comment: Since I could not trigger events in the solution provided by @elclanrs and this solution is waaay more intuitive and versatile, i'm marking this as accepted.